# iOS - How to implement tap on a button on XCUITest for Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uitest

I am wondering how to implement tap event on a button on UI test for Objective C. A sample code snippet is appreciable.
I found some example which are on Swift. Can anyone help and guide for objective c.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

let button = app.buttons["Start"]
button.tap()
```

I want this similar implementation on objective c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer,

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.buttons[@"Start"] tap];
```